# Programatically Compile multiple files when some has error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

I have to programmatically compile thousands of dynamically generated Java Files. Some of these files may have dependencies with others; but this is not a requirements so there may be simple isolated Java files as well in the mix.
Now, I am using the JavaCompiler API and the Diagnostics for this; as well as a BundleFileManager in one complex version.

However I have just discovered that if I try to compile 3 files (each of them isolated, without inner-dependencies) in the same CompilationUnit and one of them has any compilation error; no class is generated. I was expecting that the Java compiler would generate the 2 correct classes and not the incorrect one.
Someone can explain me why? if this is a technical constraint of the Java Compiler or if there is some option that can be put like (eagerApproach)?

I add the code of my dummy prototype:

```
public static void compileSetOfFiles(String[] files)
{
    File[] srcs = new File[files.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String fil : files)
    {
        srcs[i] = new File(files[i]);
        i++;
    }
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compUnits =  fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(srcs);
     CompilationTask cU = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compUnits);   
     Boolean compRes = cU.call();
    if(compRes == true){
        System.out.println("Compilation has succeeded");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Compilation error");
        try {
            fileManager.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be run with a simple main passing as arguments the filePaths to be compiled. In my case "./resources/Correct1.java" "./resources/Correct2.java" "./resources/Incorrect1.java" where

Correct1 is:

```
public class Correct1 {

    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
     }
}
```

Correct2 is:

```
public class Correct2 
{
    private String hello;


    public Correct2(String say)
    {
       hello = say;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return hello;
    }
 }
```

Incorrect1 is:

```
public class Incorrect1 
{
   as;
}
```

Comment: i dont think the fact (boolean) that it compiles will give you the compiled file at least the doc of the JavaCompiler looks like that the file manager is used for file reading and not for a write

Comment: As far as I know, and following javaCompiler API this is the way to get the FileManager. If I want to specify a different output folder than the default (which for the test is fine) I should use String[] options = new String[] { "-d", "output" }; and then pass those options to the CompilationTask. In any case, the classes are generated correctly when I only use Correct1.java and Correct2.java. But not if there is any java file that does not compile in the set of inputJavaFiles. Do you have any snippet about changing the FileManager for writing that I can test?

Comment: Is using ecj instead of javac an option for you? ecj can even be configured to process sources with errors all the way down even producing class files if so desired.

Comment: HI @StephanHerrmann. sadly it is not possible to use ecj due to licensing problems and technologies having to be approved by client :(

Comment: I cannot argue against client requirements (although clients typically don't see / care which build tools you use, do they?). But "licensing problems" sounds weird. I'm not aware of anything relevant, which EPL would not allow you to do - I must be missing s.t.